# Compile Error While Assigning Void Function to Auth Event

Tags: c#, api, authentication, spotify

I am building an application that needs Spotify to authenticate a user using `ImplicitGrantAuth`. I have set up my application on Spotify's dev and have a `ClientID`. I am using `JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET` for this application.

- API documentation of Implicit Grant Auth can be found
  [here](http://johnnycrazy.github.io/SpotifyAPI-NET/SpotifyWebAPI/auth/#implicitgrantauth).
- Spotify's documentation of Implicit Grant Flow can be found
  [here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#implicit_grant_flow).
- The original class for `ImplicitGrantAuth` can be found
  [here](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET/blob/master/SpotifyAPI/Web/Auth/ImplicitGrantAuth.cs).

**Code snippet:**

```
static ImplicitGrantAuth auth;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Create the auth object
    auth = new ImplicitGrantAuth()
    {
        //Your client Id
        ClientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", // example only
        //Set this to localhost if you want to use the built-in HTTP Server
        RedirectUri = "http://localhost",
        //How many permissions we need?
        Scope = Scope.UserReadPrivate,
    };
    //Start the internal http server
    auth.StartHttpServer();
    //When we got our response
    auth.OnResponseReceivedEvent += auth_OnResponseReceivedEvent; // <-- Error here!
    //Start
    auth.DoAuth();
}

static void auth_OnResponseReceivedEvent(Token token, string state, string error)
{
    //stop the http server
    auth.StopHttpServer();

    var spotify = new SpotifyWebAPI()
    {
        TokenType = token.TokenType,
        AccessToken = token.AccessToken
    };
    //We can now make calls with the token object
}
```

**Compile Error:**

> No overload for 'auth_OnResponseReceivedEvent' matches delegate 'SpotifyAPI.Web.Auth.ImplicitGrantAuth.OnResponseReceived'

I am not sure if I am overlooking something really simple or if I need to add something in particular. I am also pretty new to using event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many parameters in your `auth_OnResponseReceivedEvent` method. There is no `string state` parameter in the `OnResponseReceived` delegate:

```
public delegate void OnResponseReceived(Token token, String error);

public event OnResponseReceived OnResponseReceivedEvent;
```